# Curve associated to bipartite graph

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, linear-algebra, algebraic-curves, bipartite-graphs

Given real biadjacency matrix $A\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ of a bipartite graph with rank $r\in[2,n-1]$, denote $A(x)$ to be matrix where $0$ is replaced by $x$ and $1$ by $1-x$. Denote $$p_1(t,x)=Det(tI-A(x))$$ $$p_2(t,x)=Det(tI-A(x)A'(x))$$ where $A'(x)$ is transpose of $A(x)$.

One can read off rank of $A$ from highest $m$ such that $t^m|p_2(t,0)$. Roots of polynomial $p_1(t,0)$ have special meaning to graph properties.

Could considering curves $p_1(t,x)=0$ or $p_2(t,x)=0$ shed more light on bipartite graph properties?